# Get parent category(taxonomy) ID from single template of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

```
-Parent-category
    -Sub-category
```

Want to get parent ID when on the current post of `sub-category`.
Created a custom post type and custom taxonomies for that post type.
Created a category and assigned another category to have the first category as a parent.
I'm listing all posts of that parent category on the parent category page when a particular post is clicked it opens the `single-custom_post_type.php` and want to get the parent category ID on the `single-custom_post_type.php` so I can add a sidebar with all the sibling's post with the same parent category.

Any help?

```
$args_docs   =   array(
    'post_type'         =>  Documents::DOCUMENTS_TYPE_KEY,
    'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  =>  DocumentsTaxonomy::DOCUMENTS_TAXONOMY_KEY,
            'field'     =>  'term_id',
            'terms'     =>  9, // <- I want here to add the parent category ID dynamically,so whenever we are currently on a post it gives that posts parent category ID
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get Object Terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/) : Retrieves an array of `WP_Term` object associated with the given post, in the supplied taxonomies.

**[Term object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) ( `WP_Term` )offers some handy information. For example,**

Gives you term `slug`: e.g.: `term-slug-example`

```
$slug = $term->slug;
```

Gives you term `name`: e.g. `Term Name Example`

```
$name = $term->name;
```

Gives you term `description`: e.g. `This is my new cool custom term`.

```
$desc = $term->description;
```

But unfortunately lacks a link value. So use [Get Term Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) to generate a permalink for a taxonomy term archive.

```
$term_link = get_term_link( $term);
```

**So your finalcode should look like this:**

```
$sub_cats = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, DocumentsTaxonomy::DOCUMENTS_TAXONOMY_KEY, ); // array of categories associated with current post


$args_docs   =   array(
    'post_type'         =>  Documents::DOCUMENTS_TYPE_KEY,
    'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  =>  DocumentsTaxonomy::DOCUMENTS_TAXONOMY_KEY,
            'field'     =>  'term_id',
            'terms'     =>  $sub_cats[0]->parent, 
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks man! You helped a lot.